# Is there a fundamental reason why only one library can be exposed from a package?

Tags: haskell, module, dependencies, libraries, cabal

From [the latest version of the doc](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-package-description-file.html#library) I read

> A package can have no more than one unnamed library.

**Why does this limitation exist? Is it just a "temporary" limitation that could be lifted sooner or later, or is it "necessary" to Haskell's build model-or-something?**

---

From that limitation I understand that I can have at most one `library` stanza in my `.cabal` file, which in turn means that if I want multiple `exposed-modules`s from this library they must share `build-depends`.

What options do I have if I want to avoid multiple exposed modules from sharing *all* their dependencies?

The only thing I can think of, is that I could have each module be exposed by its own package.

Now, if the sets of dependencies of the two modules to be exposed have no intersection (say module `A` depends on module `A2`, and module `B` depends on module `B2`), that would be fine, and I could also ask myself *"why have I put those two modules in the same package in the first place, if they have nothing to do with each other? Just create package `A` exposing `A` with `A2` being internal library with its own dependencies, ..."*

However, if the intersection is not null (say module `A` depends on `A2` and `C`, and module `B` depends on `B2` and `C`, with `A2`, `B2`, `C` being implementation details), then, it does make sense for them to share some dependencies. But once I've made `A` and `B` separate packages, then also they're common dependencies have to be (each single one or all of them together) a standalone package. Which means... that I'd have to publish and expose 3 or more packages, even if I only meant to expose two.

---

**What is the recommended way to operate in this case?**

Comment: You can have more libraries if you `name` them. (I am not sure if this helps, but you might have missed the word "unnamed" in the line you quote)

Comment: @chi, my understanding is that named libraries are internal. I'm pretty sure I read that... maybe in an older version of the doc? Ooops, that's the case: _This guide refers to [...] a named library as a sublibrary [...] Before version 3.0 of the Cabal specification, all sublibraries were internal libraries_.

Comment: It looks like you can you can set the visibility to public with newer Cabal. (I don't know if that would be enough for your issue -- I do not fully understand it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cabal-package-description-file.html#library), I was just looking at some old version of the doc.

Here's what the new has to say

> Before version 3.0 of the Cabal specification, all sublibraries were internal libraries. Before version 2.0, a package could not include sublibraries.